# how to print Nested Array in php

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I want help on this block of code

```
foreach ($summary as $key => $value) 
{
    if ($key === "Incs") {
        foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            foreach ($subvalue as $subsubkey => $subsubvalue) {
                echo "$subsubkey:\n";
                foreach ($subsubvalue as $subsubsubkey => $subsubsubvalue) {
                    echo $subsubsubvalue;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "$key: $value\n";
    }
}
```

that is working by printing values of sub array `echo $subsubsubvalue;` but I want to use key to access each value like `echo $subsubsubvalue[$subsubsubkey];` which seems to generate error. Is there anyway possible to achieve that?

```
foreach ($summary as $key => $value) 
{
    if ($key === "Incs") {
        foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            foreach ($subvalue as $subsubkey => $subsubvalue) {
                echo "$subsubkey:\n";
                foreach ($subsubvalue as $subsubsubkey => $subsubsubvalue) {
                    echo  $subsubsubvalue[$subsubsubkey];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "$key: $value\n";
    }
}
```

Here is the array Wich I am trying print

array(8) { ["Eid"]=> string(6) "891551" ["Tr1"]=> string(1) "2" ["Tr2"]=> string(1) "0" ["Trh1"]=> string(1) "2" ["Trh2"]=> string(1) "0" ["Tr1OR"]=> string(1) "0" ["Tr2OR"]=> string(1) "0" ["Incs"]=> array(1) { [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(12) { ["Min"]=> int(24) ["Nm"]=> int(1) ["Aid"]=> string(5) "57092" ["ID"]=> string(5) "57092" ["Fn"]=> string(7) "Si-heon" ["Ln"]=> string(3) "Lee" ["Pnum"]=> int(0) ["Pn"]=> string(11) "Si-Heon Lee" ["PnumO"]=> int(0) ["IT"]=> int(36) ["Sc"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(0) } ["Sor"]=> int(3) } [1]=> array(9) { ["Min"]=> int(32) ["Nm"]=> int(1) ["ID"]=> string(7) "1067481" ["Pnum"]=> int(0) ["Pn"]=> string(13) "Dong-Ryul Lee" ["PnumO"]=> int(0) ["IT"]=> int(36) ["Sc"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(0) } ["Sor"]=> int(5) } } } }

## I want to show them in table
Time | Player | Incident

36'.  Debryne. Goal
45'.  Martial. Yellow card

Comment: What error do you get, exactly? Also, it's very difficult for us to comment on this if you don't show us some sample data, so we know what the code is trying to process. If you could show the output of `var_export($summary);` in your question that would help us a lot. See also [ask] and how to produce a [mre] of your issue. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: `$subsubsubkey` is a key of `$subsubvalue`, not `$subsubsubvalue`. So you could write `echo $subsubvalue[$subsubsubkey];`.

Comment: Why do you want to write it that way? Isn't `$subsubsubvalue` easier to write?

Comment: What you wrote would only work if the value of `$subsubvalue[$subsubsubkey]` were another array that has the same key as `$subsubvalue`. But in that case the first code wouldn't work because you can't echo arrays.

Comment: Instead of hammering with [How can I access an array/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30680938/2943403), I've vote to close as a typo question.  You already know to access array data in a loop -- you simply failed to do it in the innermost loop.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to access the value using the key when you're already looping through the values of the innermost array. To achieve what you want, you should just echo the key and value within the innermost loop directly. You don't need to use the key to access the value again, as you already have the value in $subsubsubvalue.

Also you may use $ssk, and $ssv as shorthand names.
And as recomendation use functions for recursivity and call it after the first *foreach*

```
function rPrintNestedArray($array, $indent = 0) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo str_repeat(" ", $indent * 4) . "$key:\n";
            rPrintNestedArray($value, $indent + 1);
        } else {
            echo str_repeat(" ", $indent * 4) . "$key: $value\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Your code should look like.

```
    foreach ($summary as $key => $value) 
{
    if ($key === "Incs") {
        foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            foreach ($subvalue as $subsubkey => $subsubvalue) {
                echo "$subsubkey:\n";
                foreach ($subsubvalue as $subsubsubkey => $subsubsubvalue) {
                    echo "$subsubsubkey: $subsubsubvalue\n";
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "$key: $value\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a [simpler recursive indentation script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684584/2943403) or [with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424508/2943403)